# excel: 0 in [h]:mm format becomes -1 when I save it to another file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

*Let's say I have an excel file. A1 value is 0. Its format is [h]:mm.
And I want to copy that value and save it to another excel file.
But that value becomes -1. Why is it happening?
Can anyone help me?

[image]

A1 value is 0.(see above)

[image]

I copied the value of A1 and pasted it to another excel file and saved it. 
Now it changed to -1.

Here is my code.
[image]

I want to copy and paste without changing any value. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have **only** copied the value, you have to assing the style `format is [h]:mm` to `ws2['a1']` **too**. Read [stable/styles.html#applying-styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#applying-styles)

Comment: Datetimes are weird in Excel, especially because you always have to provide the relevant format date or time format.

Comment: To stovfl: sorry, but it does not matter if we add ws2['A1'].number_format = '[h]:mm'. I tested and it is still not working.

Comment: To Charlie: Is there a way to copy the value without changing?

Comment: @Charlie Clark see my answer below. Is this a bug or working as designed?

Answer (score 0):

The best I can tell this is due to the way that openpyxl currently handles the epoch time when saving to the file. It looks like Excel is actually storing your `0:00` as a datetime even though you are only showing the time part of the datetime.

One work around to this would be to add a date component to the time (so it doesn't default to the epoch). For example set the time to `2018-01-01 0:00` and then format it to `h:mm`

Not sure if this approach will meet all your requirements but it did copy over without the `-1` for me

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: openpyxl actually lets you store datetimes explicitly as such rather than relying on the inherently flawed serials that Excel defaults to. Set `wb.iso_dates=True`. But there are limits to this because deltas have no ISO representation. Basically, Excel is really not suitable for working with datetimes.